# Saving URLs of website viewed by the user to a log file in win32 API

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a win32 API application in visual c++ in which I want to save URLs of website viewed by the user to a log file. Can any guide me in trouble shooting above problem.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as a service... Then, using pcap, simply watch the traffic flowing across your network interface... When you see HTTP headers, nab the URL's...

Comment: Hi dicroce, Thanks for you pormpt response. I am new to win32 API can you Please guide me how to capture pcap in visual C++.